# CakePHP 2.0: Preparing data from a different model by the AppController for a Helper?

Tags: cakephp, model

I've made a helper, that should output some data from my database in the layout, so this data have to be available everywhere. Now I tried to load and set a variable by the AppController, but it seems I can not use the usual find()-method. Here's my error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\propfe\Controller\AppController.php on line 46
```

That's how I tried to load the Model, once by the $uses-variable and once by the App::import()-Command:

```
var $uses = 'Surgeryhour';

App::import('Model','Surgeryhour');
```

And here's the line 46 of the error:

```
$this->set('data', $this->Surgeryhour->find(null, '1'));
```

Any ideas how I can get all this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try load model like this:

```
$this->loadModel('Surgeryhour');
$this->set('data', $this->Surgeryhour->find(null, '1'));
```

Don't need variable `$uses`.

Answer (score 1):

never use App::import for models

always:

```
$this->Surgeryhour = ClassRegistry::init('Surgeryhour');
```